# How to read and store string in UTF-8 format in C#?

Tags: c#, utf-8

I have a file with URLs, one of which is [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/São_Paulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Paulo). Note that 'ã'. When I read the URLs (in C#) and try to print it, it appears as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S?o_Paulo.

I tried reading the URLs as following:

```
List<string> urls = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(wikiURL_FilePath, Encoding.UTF8).ToList();
```

Note that I have passed second argument to read it in UTF8 format, but still the problem is not rectified. How can I read and store the string in correct form?

Comment: Have you tried reading the file as unicode?

Comment: Where and how are you printing it? It is entirely possible (and likely) that the problem is at the display end, not the reading end. What are the bytes of the file? Can you show a hex dump of the file, perhaps?

Comment: Does it showed in `Notepad` correctly? In the other hand is it saved correctly?

Comment: BTW: urls should really be %-encoded

Comment: @afsharm notepad isn't perhaps the best tool to answer that question ;p

Comment: Printing it on console and also trying to download that page. Printing happens as mentioned above and the downloaded page shows the following:

`The requested page title contains an invalid UTF-8 sequence.

Return to Main Page.` which indicates that URL was not correct.

Comment: The console doesn't have great unicode support, so that isn't a shocker. How are you doing the download thing? And again: URLs should be % encoded - I have to agree with it: at the raw level, that is **simply not** a valid URL, despite what browsers would have you believe. The correct url is: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A3o_Paulo`

Comment: @MarcGravell Notepad shows text (not binaries) files correctly, at least until now I thought so. What's its problem?

Comment: @afsharm until recently, notepad unicode support was **terrible**; it is much better now, but it will  still get confused if the encoding is not obvious and there is no BOM. However, I doubt that the underlying problem here is anything to do with file  reading...

Comment: @Bit: **please show the binary file contents** relating to this line; until then, *nobody can reliably help you*.

Comment: Check the file-encoding, probably it says ANSI. Convert it to UTF-8 or Unicode using a tool like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and your code will work.

Comment: @MarcGravell how to see the binary file content?

Comment: I changed the encoding in notepad++ from ANSI to UTF-8 and now it appears as `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S䰟Paulo`

Comment: @Bit this should work: `var hex = BitConverter.ToString(File.ReadAllBytes(wikiURL_FilePath));` (and show the contents of `hex`)

Comment: Hex content: `EF-BB-BF-68-74-74-70-3A-2F-2F-65-6E-2E-77-69-6B-69-70-65-64-69-61-2E-6F-72-67-2F
-77-69-6B-69-2F-41-74-6C-61-6E-74-61-0D-0A-68-74-74-70-3A-2F-2F-65-6E-2E-77-69-6
B-69-70-65-64-69-61-2E-6F-72-67-2F-77-69-6B-69-2F-4B-65-79-5F-57-65-73-74-2C-5F-
46-6C-6F-72-69-64-61-0D-0A-68-74-74-70-3A-2F-2F-65-6E-2E-77-69-6B-69-70-65-64-69
-61-2E-6F-72-67-2F-77-69-6B-69-2F-53-E3-6F-5F-50-61-75-6C-6F-0D-0A-68-74-74-70-3
A-2F-2F-65-6E-2E-77-69-6B-69-70-65-64-69-61-2E-6F-72-67-2F-77-69-6B-69-2F-50-69-
74-74-73-62-75-72-67-68-0D-0A-68-74-74-70-3A-2F-2F-65-6E-2E-77-69-6B-69-70-65-64....`

Comment: Now we're talking; one moment... the good news is that it is explicitly UTF-8, so: ignore the ANSI comment

Comment: that is because may be i changed it to utf-8 by using the notepad++ as said in that comment.

Comment: Ok, after reverting too, it looks same.

Comment: The data you have shown is simply not UTF-8, despite have a UTF-8 BOM; the UTF-8 for `São` is `53-C3-A3-6F`; you have `53-E3-6F`, which is... the right byte-codes, but incorrectly encoded to  disk; how was the file written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you have shown is simply not UTF-8, despite having a UTF-8 BOM; the UTF-8 for São is 53-C3-A3-6F; you have 53-E3-6F, which is... the right unicode code-points for basic multi-lingual plane data, but incorrectly encoded to disk as UTF-8. You probably need to fix the code that *wrote* this file, or: agree on what the encoding is (it could be a single-byte code-page, but you need to agree which, else everything falls apart).

Likely looking encodings (if  we take away the BOM):

- utf-7
- windows-1252
- windows-1254
- iso-8859-1
- iso-8859-4
- iso-8859-9
- iso-8859-15